# Hibernate order by fields that might be null

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jpa, hql

My guess is that this question is answered somewhere, but I can't seem to find the proper key words to search for.

I have these entities:

```
@Entity
Entity1{
    <random fields>

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "entity_2")
    Entity2 e2;//might be null.
}

@Entity
Entity2{
    <random fields>
    String name;
}
```

I want to write a query that returns all my Entity1's ordered by the name of their Entity2's. I've tried this:

```
SELECT e1 from Entity1 e1 ORDER BY e1.e2.name ASC
```

The problem with the above query (tested on mysql) is that it only returns Entity1's where e2 is not null.

What i need is a way to get all Entity1's, even if e2 is null.

Ps. Ive' also tried these with the same result:

```
SELECT e1 from Entity1 e1 ORDER BY e1.e2 ASC, e1.e2.name ASC
SELECT e1 from Entity1 e1 ORDER BY e1.e2.name ASC, e1.e2 ASC
```

Thanks in advance!
//hql newbie

**EDIT :**
Added jpa -annotations that I use.

Answer (score 0):

if you are Using JPA, using of Annotations is very simple for your problem.. in that way i'm giving one example using Annotaion

When you have collections of associated objects in domain objects, you generally want to specify some kind of default sort order. For example, suppose I have domain objects Timeline and Event:

```
@Entity
class Event {

    @Required
    Integer startYear

    Integer endYear

    @Required
    String description

    @ManyToOne
    Timeline timeline
}
```

This sort order is the same as using the JPA @OrderBy with "startYear, endYear" sort order. But since you write actual SQL in Hibernate's @OrderBy you can take advantage of whatever features your database has, at the possible expense of portability across databases. As an example, Oracle 10g supports using a syntax like "order by start_year, end_year nulls first" to order null end years before non-null end years.

@org.hibernate.annotations.OrderBy. Adding a SQL fragment into your domain class isn't necessarily the most elegant thing in the world, but it might be the most pragmatic thing.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, your suggestion is to add @OrderBy("name") on the e2 field in Entity1? Unfortunately, the chans that we will need to sort on some other attribute later on is quite big..